# How to avoid pylab.savefig generated image collapsed taxa axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, biopython

I'm working on BioPython when my data input is large size. The function `pylab.savefig` generate the `png` figure with collapsed taxa axis.

Here is my code for generate figure:

```
def generate_img():
def get_label(leaf):
    return leaf.name

f = filepath
tree = Phylo.read(f, 'newick')
#tree.ladderize()   # Flip branches so deeper clades are displayed at top

Phylo.draw(tree, label_func=get_label, do_show=False, branch_labels=lambda c: c.branch_length)

# axis management
pylab.axis('on')
pylab.savefig('output.png', format='png',  bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100, bbox_extra_artists=[])
```

And the result output:

[image: Actual output]

My excepted output look like this:

[image: My accepted output should look like]